# Unable to change Azure Data Factory subscription

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to change/migrate a Data Factory resource from one subscription to another in Azure and I'm getting an odd JSON error which I'm not sure if it's an issue with the portal itself or whether there is a true validation error that is stopping it from being changed.

```
 {
  "message": "Cannot read property 'responseJSON' of undefined",
  "name": "TypeError",
  "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseJSON' of undefined\n    at c (https://portal.azure.com/AzureHubs/Content/Dynamic/hUQmInOzYJjx.js:2:668)\n    at o (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/ACdWT39XjnDc.js:4:72)\n    at https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/ACdWT39XjnDc.js:4:5711"
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUkii.png)

Comment: Does the Data Factory validate in the Monitor and Manage UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will receive this error message when you don’t have permissions on the destination subscription or Resource Group which you are trying to move the resources.

Make sure the account which you are trying to move the resources has permission in both the destinations Subscription and Resource Group.

Go to **Access control (IAM)** settings for both Subscription and Resource Group and the user is added as an **owner** or **administrator**.

Once you grant the owner permissions on your associates account, I’m able to move the resources without any issue.